# Vba macro runs on home computer and gets error 2147417848 on work computer

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, runtime-error

With the help of the forum, I created a macro that connects to the web of my bank, fill in the username and password and enter my account. The macro copies the account balance and pastes it into Excel.

On my home computer, it works without problems. However, the work computer does not work. In my workplace, the macro opens the web but does not fill in the user or the password. It stops in the line `While. Busy Or.readyState <4` and the error `Runtime Error 2147417848` comes out.

I added "activobank.com" to the trusted sites of Explorer and the error follows.

I have checked `Explorer> Tools> Internet Options> Connections> LAN settings> Detect settings selected` and it is selected. My workplace do not run proxy scripts.

If I enter Manually in Internet Explorer without using macro and I put the user and password, I can enter without problems.

What can be the problem for the macro to work on my home computer and not on my work computer?

```
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub SaldoActivo()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        ‘Navigate first web
        .Navigate2 "https://www.activobank.com/cs/Satellite/BC/"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.querySelector("[name=userDNI]").Value = "123456789"
        .document.querySelector("[name=pinNif]").Value = "123456789"
        .document.querySelector("#button1").Click
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        ' Navigate second page
        .Navigate2 "https://www.activobank.com/activobank/CUGlobalPositionNew.init.bs"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    End With

‘Code to copy the account balance data
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:04"))

Cells(1, 1) = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(39).innerText

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug the code and when the error occurs, check if `IE.hwnd` returns any value. If it doesn't there is a problem with your IE's security settings, afaik IE opens a new browser when it navigates to website that's in different security zone (for example from local intranet to Internet). Try enabling protected mode for both of these, or/and set the same security level.

/e: If none of the settings mentioned in comments below make any difference, create an instance of Internet Explorer running at a medium integrity level: `Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium`

Comment: Same answer I was going to give. +1. You should also be able to check security settings via your vba

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not have enough knowledge. Could you give me step-by-step instructions to do what you ask?

Comment: @germangp which part do you not understand? On error, debug the code and type "?IE.hwnd" in immediate window to see if it returns any value. If it doesn't, browser's security settings are the problem

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I have little knowledge of vba. Once I have given the error, I have written "? IE.hwnd" in the immediate window. A window opens that says Error 462, the server computer does not exist or is not available.

Comment: Right, that's a good sign - it just confirms that there's a problem with your browser's security settings. Did you try to check "Enable Protected Mode" in "Internet" and "Local intranet" zones, in security tab?

Comment: I have been to "Internet Explorer / Internet Options / Security / Internet / Enable Protected Mode". It was marked so I left it like that.
Then in "Internet Explorer / Internet Options / Security / Local Intranet / Enable Protected Mode". It was unchecked so I have marked it and I have left Internet Explorer.
I have run the macro and Runtime Error 2147417848 has come out again. I have put the window immediately "? IE.hwnd" and again I get "Error 462, the server does not exist or is not available".

Comment: Did you restart IE? There is another setting that you might need to change, click "Custom level..." and enable "Websites with less privileged web content zone can navigate into this zone" - again, enable this in both zones. It that doesn't work, try to set both zones to the same security level.

Comment: I have done both. First I checked "Websites with less privileged web content zone can navigate into this zone". It was activated. I have executed the macro and the error continues.
Then I put the two in low security, I have executed the macro and the error continues.

Comment: That's odd. I have one other idea. Try "Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium" instead of what you've got in the code.

Comment: :-) Perfect, that was the problem. It works now. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: That's great! I'll edit my original post to include it. Don't forget to mark this as correct response please :)

Comment: One last thing, could you recommend me manuals on vba and how to copy data from web pages to Excel? I would like to improve my knowledge on these subjects.

Comment: There are quite a lot good tutorials on google - I can't recommend you anything specific, you can google "web scraping with vba". You'll need some basic html knowledge as well, check out w3schools. Then if you hit a brick wall, post your question on SO :)

Comment: I will look where you tell me. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrPEAljQjRM&list=PLNIs-AWhQzcl3xKvF8sVL4sWRWICj_clM